# Issue rake assets:precompile with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, rake

I am using Rails 3.2 , but when I use `rake assets:precompile` it generates this error. I can't figure out why this error is been generated, and how to fix it.

```
cp -r /home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/bundler/gems/tinymce-rails-f7dd26ee75b5/assets/precompiled/tinymce /path_to_app/public/assets
/path_to_app/new/orthomind/config/Gemfile not found
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (10): [/home/nazar2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/b...]
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:53:in `block in create_shell_runner'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `call'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:45:in `sh'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `sh'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:80:in `ruby'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:39:in `ruby'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/home/nazar2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@3.2/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

How can I diagnose the issue?

NOTE: I tested that its not a `tinymce-rails` gem error, because I tried to remove it from the whole app but still it generate the same error.